How to Automatically Fill a Login Form After Basic Authentication in Flutter's InAppWebView?
Description:
I'm developing a Flutter application using the flutter_inappwebview package. Here is the flow that I need to handle:
Initial Access: When accessing the URL https://x.catalogue, a basic authentication prompt appears asking for a username and password. I handle this using the CookieManager to set the appropriate cookies, which works correctly.
Redirection to Login Page: After successful basic authentication, the page redirects to a login page (https://x.login), which contains a login form with separate fields for a username and password.
Problem: I need to automatically fill in this login form (username and password) using JavaScript injection or another method since this login step requires user input into form fields rather than handling via cookies.
What I've Tried:
Using CookieManager to set cookies, but this only works for the initial basic authentication and does not apply to the form fields on the login page.
Injecting JavaScript to fill in the username and password fields:
 Future<void> injectLoginForm(InAppWebViewController controller) async {
  String jsCode = """
    document.querySelector('input[name="username"]').value = 'myUsername';
    document.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value = 'myPassword';
    document.querySelector('form').submit();
  """;

  await controller.evaluateJavascript(source: jsCode);
}

Question:
How can I reliably fill out the login form fields on the second page (https://x.login) after the basic authentication without being disrupted by page refreshes or other events?
Are there specific techniques or best practices in flutter_inappwebview for handling this kind of scenario where both cookie-based authentication and form submission are needed?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
